# How do I get my Mono 4.2 code to send email through Amazon SES?

Tags: ssl, mono, smtp, x509certificate, amazon-ses

I have Mono (version 4.2.1) code running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS; that code 's trying and failing to send email using Amazon SES. From other searches I read that the error is due to certificates not being present in mono's trust store. The command to fix this being:
mozroots --import --ask-remove

followed by:

certmgr -ssl smtps://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:587

(since email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com is the SMTP server I'm using; on port 587)

The first command works fine and imported 162 certificates to my store.
The second command fails with an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e7020 + 0x00132> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x402e6f50 + 0x00031> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x402e3aa0 + 0x00225> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) <0x402e7cf0 + 0x000ec> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e7a40 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e1190 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () <0x402da8b0 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x402da4d0 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder) <0x7f07ce354da0 + 0x000fa> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () <0x7f07ce354d70 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) <0x402a43e0 + 0x00357> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, Boolean machine, Boolean verbose) <0x402a39f0 + 0x0013a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) <0x4029ed70 + 0x004f0> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e7020 + 0x00132> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x402e6f50 + 0x00031> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x402e3aa0 + 0x00225> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) <0x402e7cf0 + 0x000ec> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e7a40 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndNegotiateHandshake (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.InternalAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x402e1190 + 0x0007b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.NegotiateHandshake () <0x402da8b0 + 0x000b6> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x402da4d0 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush (Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder) <0x7f07ce354da0 + 0x000fa> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () <0x7f07ce354d70 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.GetCertificatesFromSslSession (System.String url) <0x402a43e0 + 0x00357> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Ssl (System.String host, Boolean machine, Boolean verbose) <0x402a39f0 + 0x0013a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Tools.CertificateManager.Main (System.String[] args) <0x4029ed70 + 0x004f0> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the common failures of `certmgr` is not running it with `sudo`. It produces that `Exception`, which is a really misleading.

On macOS/Linux:

```
certmgr -ssl smtps://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:587
```

will produce the exact error you posted.

Using sudo:

```
sudo certmgr -ssl smtps://email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:587
```

results in:

```
X.509 Certificate v3
   Issued from: C=US, O=Equifax, OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
   Issued to:   C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   Valid from:  5/21/2002 4:00:00 AM
   Valid until: 8/21/2018 4:00:00 AM
   *** WARNING: Certificate signature is INVALID ***
Import this certificate into the CA store ?yes

X.509 Certificate v3
   Issued from: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   Issued to:   C=US, O=Google Inc, CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   Valid from:  4/1/2015 12:00:00 AM
   Valid until: 12/31/2017 11:59:59 PM
   *** WARNING: Certificate signature is INVALID ***
Import this certificate into the CA store ?yes

X.509 Certificate v3
   Issued from: C=US, O=Google Inc, CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   Issued to:   C=US, S=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=smtp.gmail.com
   Valid from:  4/12/2017 1:28:00 PM
   Valid until: 7/5/2017 1:28:00 PM
Import this certificate into the AddressBook store ?yes

3 certificates added to the stores.
```

Note: Make sure you are answering `yes` to the import question.

Comment: I tried running it with sudo and got the exact same error. Is it possible that my first attempt (without sudo) could have corrupted something in the system? How then would I rollback those changes?

Comment: @Cois No, it should not mess any up... I just tried it again, without sudo same error, with sudo I get the 3 certs reported and that they are already in the CA store...

Comment: @Cois Personally, I would move up to mono 4.8 as the Google's BoringSSL was added to replace the managed provider in order to add TLS 1.1/1.2 support. Getting away from the managed provider removed a lot of problems and using mozroots is not longer needed as the system cert store is used... Amazon does still support tls1.0/1.0 (at least for now) on their smtp servers so mono 4.2 *should* work....